# Rails 6 : How to retreive a csv file in /tmp in order to send via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a CRON JOB in order to create a CSV file once a month and send it to an API

My method bellow generates a csv file in /tmp folder

```
  def save_csv_to_tmp
    f = Tempfile.create(["nb_administrateurs_par_mois_#{date_last_month}", '.csv'], 'tmp')
    f << generate_csv
    f.close
  end
```

Now, in the perform method, I have to retreive this csv file but I do not know how to do it :

```
def perform(*args)
    # creates the csv file in tmp folder
    save_csv_to_tmp
    # TODO : retreive this csv file and send it to the API
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (Using the block version of `Tempfile#create`, it will automatically close and unlink the temporary file):

```rb
  def save_csv_to_tmp
    Tempfile.create(["nb_administrateurs_par_mois_#{date_last_month}", '.csv'], 'tmp'] do |f|
      f << generate_csv
      # You might need to call `f.rewind` here 
      # so that your service object can use the file object right away

      yield f if block_given?
    end
  end
```

And in perform

```rb
def perform(*args)
    save_csv_to_tmp do |file|
       # Send file to API
       SendFileService.new(file: file).call # Or something similar
    end
end
```

Comment: You might want to `unlink` the tempfile afterwards or alternatively use the block form for `create` which does this automatically. Depending on how `SendFileService` works, you might even want to `close` the file _before_ yielding.

Comment: @Stefan Indeed, I edited my answer to take your remarks into consideration, thanks.